# SQL Agent and Web.Config. WAS: SSRS Forms Authentication, Running subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, forms-authentication

I have successfully implemented Forms Authentication in SSRS, so it now uses both Roles and Users from my website, using the ordinary asp.net membership framework.

I can log in to the portal and run any report, as long as I have the correct role from my original app. All good.

However, if I create a subscription, then, when the subscription runs, I don't get my report, but rather this message in the log:

```
    subscription!WindowsService_0!161a0!10/21/2009-22:42:05:: i INFO: 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: 
An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> 
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException:
 The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
       at System.Web.Security.Roles.EnsureEnabled()
       at System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(String username)
       at MyApp.ReportServer.Security.Module.Authorization.CheckAccess(String userName, IntPtr userToken, Byte[] secDesc, ReportOperation requiredOperation)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Security.CheckAccess(ItemType catItemType, Byte[] secDesc, ReportOperation rptOper, String reportPath)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SecurityRequirements.CheckAccess(ItemType itemType, Byte[] securityDescriptor, String itemPath)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.DefinitionLoader.GetParameterDefinition(CatalogItemContext itemContext, String historyId, Boolean forRendering, SecurityRequirements requirements)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSService.GetReportParameters(ClientRequest session, CatalogItemContext reportContext, Boolean forRendering)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSServiceDataProvider.GetParameters(ClientRequest session, CatalogItemContext reportContext)
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderForNewSession.GetReportParameters()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderForNewSession.GetReportMetadata()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderForNewSession.get_ExecuteExistingSnapshot()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderForNewSession.GetExecutionStrategy()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecutionBase.InternalExecuteReport()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecutionBase.Execute()
       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CancelablePhaseBase.ExecuteWrapper()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The MyApp line is my custom security extension.

I have the RoleManager and membership provider setup in web.config in the /ReportServer directory.

Does the subscription runner circumvent the website settings somehow?

UPDATE:

Ok, so I found out, that apparently it is running with whatever is values is set in MACHINE.CONFIG when a subscription is being evaluated/triggered by sql agent.

Any clues why it doesn't use the web.config settings, but goes straight to machine.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not formiliar with SSRS, but I am with .NET / membership providers and web/app/machine.config.

Your exception states subscription!WindowsService_0!161a0!10/21/2009-22:42:05:: 
I think this means the subscription service is a windows service and doesn't run in IIS. This means it has a different configuration file.

http://reportserver -> IIS -> web.config (Your configuration)
subscription!WindowsService -> Services -> app.config -> machine.config.

Hope it helps.